# ¿Como subir carpeta o directorio via ajax en node?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, fetch

he querido saber como se envia un directorio via ajax o fetch o via axios hacia el backend, porque me llega la carpeta pero sin embargo me llegar un archivo via file mas no se si realmente es por esa peticion. en el frontend ya tengo para que cargue dicho directorio, lo que deseo es recibir en el backend la carpeta completa via por dicha peticion POST, ya sea directorio o ZIP. ¿como seria esto? o lo debo tratar como un archivo normal readFile ?

Comment: Tienes que tener un formulario con el atributo type seteado en `multipart-form/data` primeramente o algo asi, no recuerdo si asi esta bien escrito el multipart, lo segundo es que debes tener otro atributo especial que te permita subir directorios, con esto ya listo solo tendrias que recibir esta informacion por medio del input file en javascript y enviarla por `ajax`, luego recibirla en `nodeJS` y que nodeJS se encargue de guardar la carpeta en otra carpeta del servidor.

Comment: Eso si, la etiqueta `fetch` no tiene del todo que ver con `ajax`, pues `ajax` se entiende como una tecnologia diferente a `fetch`, sin embargo podriamos decir que ambos pueden cumplir el mismo rol.

Comment: Bueno, acabo de darme cuenta que he dicho una estupides, enrealidad si vas a enviar archivos por ajax nisiquiera necesitas un formulario, solo necesitas el input `file`.

Comment: si pero cuando envio el directorio el body me lo recibe de forma vacio y el atributo file en el backend me sale el primer archivo y mas nada y no todos los directorio  que estan dentro de ese directorio, no se si me di entender @Riven